# MSSQL CTE tree with filter how to?

Tags: sql-server, filter, tree, common-table-expression

There's a table that describes object hierarchy and their type:

```
DECLARE @TTable TABLE
(
 ID int
 ,Higher int -- for some reason this is how ID_PARENT named
 ,[Type] int
)
```

I need to select a subtree with branches only containing nodes of certain [Type]. Since I'm a beginner at SQL generally and CTE I did this by first finding all the branches that contain objects of certain type from bottom to top:

```
;WITH c
AS
(
SELECT 
    ID
    ,Higher
    ,[Type]
FROM
    dbo.EnObj
WHERE Type = 40

UNION ALL

SELECT
    t.ID
    ,t.Higher
    ,t.Type
FROM
    dbo.EnObj T
INNER JOIN c ON t.ID = c.Higher
)
```

Then chose unique records into a table variable:

```
INSERT @TTable
SELECT DISTINCT
c.ID
,c.Higher
,c.Type
,c.Name
,c.Voltage
FROM  c
```

And then built an hierarchy by CTE with sorting from top to bottom:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT
    ID
    ,Higher
    ,[Type]
,CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(128)) AS Sort
FROM    
    @TTable
WHERE
    Higher IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT
    N.ID
    ,N.Higher
    ,N.[Type]
    ,CAST(P.Sort + '/' + CAST(N.ID AS VARCHAR) AS VARCHAR(128))
FROM    
    @TTable N
INNER JOIN CTE AS P ON P.ID = N.Higher
)
SELECT 
    ID
    ,Higher
    ,[Type]
    ,Sort
FROM CTE 
ORDER BY Sort
```

It works, but I wonder if there's a way to optimize this query, like using one CTE instead of two or have a filter in CTE.

Comment: I think the last query is quite nice.

Comment: All respects go to this guy: [link](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/28/posts/10486/recursive-cte-and-ordering-of-the-hierarchical-result.aspx)

Comment: Do you want to get the hierarchy of a certain [type] below a particular [Id] ? Or all possible trees with a certain [type] ?

Comment: I need entire tree from root element (defined by [Higher] IS NULL) which contains only branches that end up with nodes with [Type] = 40.

Answer (score 1):

```
with Hierachy 
as  
(
    select ID, Higher, Type from EnObj
        WHERE Type = 40 -- Whatever your search criteria

        union all   
    select EnObj.ID, EnObj.Higher ,EnObj.Type from EnObj    
    inner join Hierachy 
    on tblOrgLevel.Higher = Hierachy.ID
 )
select * from Hierachy --where ID <> 40
```

Another solution

```
WITH DirectReports
AS 
(
    SELECT parentid, id, Title, 0 AS EmployeeLevel
    FROM dbo.tblOrgLevel  
    WHERE ISNULL(parentid ,0) = 0 and  FKAgencyID = 58
    UNION ALL
    SELECT e.parentid, e.id, e.Title, EmployeeLevel + 1
    FROM dbo.tblOrgLevel AS e
        INNER JOIN DirectReports AS d
        ON e.parentid= d.id 
)
SELECT *
FROM DirectReports
ORDER BY parentid;
GO
```

You can ask me for more clarification, and some modifications